# Array de struct aceitando mais que o definido, o que há de errado?

Tags: c, array, struct, gerenciamento-de-memória

No código eu criei um *array* do tipo `Pessoa` contendo apenas 2, mas quando começa a iterar no laço for e acessa o índice 2 e 3 o condigo continua sem gerar erro em tempo de compilação nem de execução. É normal esse comportamento?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

typedef struct{
    int num;
}Pessoa;

Pessoa pessoa[2];

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const int count = 4;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i += 1){
        pessoa[i].num = i;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i += 1)
    {
        printf("%d\n", pessoa[i].num);
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Saída do programa

```
0
1
2
3
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 2):

Completamente normal. Isso é C, você faz o que quiser e a linguagem deixa. Claro que está corrompendo a memória e não devia fazer isso, mas é permitido. Funciona, mas não está certo, em algo um pouco mais complexo que isto dará vários problemas. Você está escrevendo em um local da memória que não foi reservado para este *array*, ali possivelmente teria algo que seria perdido.

Em C vale mais ainda a máxima de que não basta fazer funcionar, tem que estar certo.

O ideal é não usar variável global, mas nesse caso não faz diferença ser local, haverá corrupção de memória em qualquer dos casos, tornar a variável local não resolve o problema. A única solução é saber o que está fazendo e não deixar acessar uma área da memória que não foi alocada para o que deseja.

Answer (score -1):

É mais ou menos normal.

Como você colocou o vetor pessoa como global, então ele permite que você saia alocando espaço infinitamente e dá muita margem para que as coisas saiam do controle.
Você pode corrigir isso colocando a variável como local no seu main. Assim ele evita que você leia algo que não foi declarado na função.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

typedef struct{
    int num;
}Pessoa;


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

    Pessoa pessoa[2];
    const int count = 4;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < count; i += 1){
        pessoa[i].num = i;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < count; i += 1)
    {
        printf("%d\n", pessoa[i].num);
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
0
1
```

E já fica a dica: Evite usar variáveis globais.